# Why was the Solidity compiler removed in geth 1.6.0?

Tags: compiler

Why was the Solidity compiler removed in geth 1.6.0? What is the procedure to deploy a contract in geth 1.6.0?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/209) is the discussion where it was decided to deprecate eth_compile.

To summarize, **it's not really geth's responsibility** to compile code. Or parity's. Or any other node's. Continuing to support in-node compilation would force nodes to host compilers written in other languages. In addition, the interface to compile was poor, as there are many more complexities to a compilation process than a single function call could provide. By removing it, several potential cans of worms were preemptively closed.

**How do we go on from here?**

A simple method is to use [remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/), which can connect to a geth node. Alternately, some frameworks have a built-in toolchain. I personally use a home-brewed [gulpfile](https://github.com/Smithgift/Impermanence/blob/develop/gulpfile.js) to automate compilation.

If you really need solc in your JS code, a JS version can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js).