# METHOD_NOT_FOUND: The method being requested is not available on this server

Tags: web3js

```
> web3.eth.getCompilers(function(err,req){if(!err)console.log(req);else console.log(err);});
```

undefined

> Error: METHOD_NOT_FOUND: The method being requested is not available on this server
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereum-console/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereum-console/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereum-console/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/ipcprovider.js:66:44
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Socket. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereum-console/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/ipcprovider.js:50:47)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>       at Pipe.onread (net.js:551:20)

Comment: Check out an explanation over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16255/why-was-the-solidity-compiler-removed-in-geth-1-6-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling via RPC has been deprecated in eth. Check: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/209